# Is there a plugin for versioning files in the theme (style , .js and .php files)?

Tags: theme-development, version-control

I checked the available wordpress plugins for versioning, but none seem to do what I need.  I would like a way to peform some simple version control on the style sheet or .php files in the theme.  Ideally a simple way so that the file history of each file is available and if a file is changed I can return to a previous version easily if needed.

Wordpress does this by defaut for pages and posts,  but I can't find a way to easily version my theme files.

Comment: This is what `git` is used for, and previously subversion/svn, this isn't something WordPress or a plugin would provide, and you'll see this in use on a lot of higher end and managed hosting providers. If you're concerned about version control then you may have moved beyond editing files via dashboard, and should look into proper code editors that run on your local computer, and local dev environments

Comment: I use git regulalrly for other coding,  so I am familiar with it.  Was hoping there would be something a bit more lightweight than having a whole git+deployment workflow.  I was actually wondering if there might be a plugin which integrated git to wordpress so that the git versioning could be used directly from wordpress.

Comment: Page and post content is stored in WordPress's database, whereas your theme/plugin files are just that—files in the filesystem. I suppose you *could* set up something where you're loading all those assets from the DB, but I'd recommend using `git` instead. (At my workplace, each plugin and theme we build is its own git repo, instead of `git`ting the whole WordPress site.)

Comment: if it's a recommendation you're after, those are off topic here, you should ask on the software recommendations stack instead

Comment: ok slightly changed title so that it is a question... @PatJ I have moved to your solution,  (locla wordpress install test and deploy css and version css files locally.  Issue however is that for large sites with multiple plugins I need to pay for the plugins for the local install and the remote.